# Girl with Magical Stones Time Traveling

Tags: story-identification

The book is most likely preteen/teen fiction. The setting wasn't quite modern world but more of a magical/scifi world.

Near the end of the book, the protagonist (who I think was a really young girl, think preteen or even younger) uses a crystal/stone (maybe red?) to travel back in time. Once they reach the start of the world, they actually go to the future and keeping traveling back in time until they arrive back in their original time.

They also dropped a man (who was the enemy?) in a time period with dinosaurs, and when the man asked how to use the crystal, the protagonist explained the process as one where they have to imagine opening an eye.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you remember any character names or the cover art?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @DavidW I don't remember any character names or the cover art. It is an English book, and I read it about 10 years ago in America. I faintly remember that it was a pretty old book back then too, but I'm not entirely too sure, could be mixing up multiple books.

Answer (score 10):

I found the book, it was *[Molly Moon's Hypnotic Time Travel Adventure](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/799072)* (2004) by Georgia Byng.

> Molly Moon meets . . . Molly Moon? In this third book in the wildly
> popular New York Times bestselling series, mesmerizing orphan Molly
> Moon and her fabulouspug, Petula, are off to India, where they
> discover a new twist in the potential power of time travel!
>
> [image]

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as 'accepted' for future visitors.

Comment: I can't tell if you've attended the [tour], but accepting an answer is done by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. As a self-answer, you won't be able to complete accepting until 48 hours after asking the question, but clicking earlier will tell you how much longer you will have to wait.